# Corona SDK 3d engine

Tags: sdk, 3d, coronasdk

I have been using Corona SDK for almost a year, and have a couple simple games developed. What I am looking for now is some way to create 3D illusions in Corona SDK. If anyone has any experience with 3D in Corona, I would appreciate any advice. I've tried several game engines, but they either don't work with Corona, or cost way too much.

Comment: what kind of 3d illusions do you mean? If you want a full 3D engine I would suggest unity over corona.

Comment: Thanks. I have unity, and it is very good, but it cost quite a bit if you want to build for Android.

Comment: You should stay away from Corona at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 3D model in [Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com), export an image, and add it to your Corona app.

If you want animations, you can also export a bunch of sprites from Sketchup (sort of) and use the [movieclip](http://blog.anscamobile.com/2010/06/improved-movieclip-library/) library to play the animation.

Comment: I have been exporting 3D images for use in Corona. I would like to find an environment like Unity that doesn't cost so much to build for Android.

Comment: Corona costs 199 for android only while Unity3D cost 400 dollars for android only.  https://store.unity3d.com/ and http://www.anscamobile.com/pricing/

Comment: Google Sketchup? it seems to be Trimble Sketchup... O_o

Comment: @Fran  It was owned by Google before May 2012.  Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 2):

Check out LIME library for Corona sdk, you can simulate 3D effect with parallax or orthogonal view. And there is some code in code sharing section of corona, but i dont know if that can be useful:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/texturemapped-raycasting-engine

http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/raycasting-engine

Comment: Thanks. I'll  check out LIME.